# AngularJS how to add numbers inside the expression from a textbox?

Tags: angularjs

I have a problem adding a number from a textbox and place it on another textbox. My situation is like this:

I have one textbox:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="num1" />
```

And whatever the input is on this textbox, this will be the value of another textbox like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ num1 + 1 }}" />
```

This setup shows successfully but with errors. When I type `2013` on the first, the second shows `20131` instead of `2014`.
I also tried using filters like this:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ num1 + 1 | number}}" />
```

but unfortunately, it doesn't work. What did I miss?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The value of a textbox is a string.
You need to convert it to an integer/float you can do that using `parseInt` or `parseFloat` if you have decimals. By default you don't have the parseInt method available in your expression, but you can add it to the scope in your controller to make it available:

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;


<input type="text" value="{{ parseInt(num1) + 1 }}" />
```

You can [see this in action here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LmnXU6)

Comment: No problem, just don't do too much maths in those expressions or it will get messy. There is usually a reason behind why simple things are more complicated in angular.

Comment: A better (in terms of readability, brevity, and performance) option than using `parseInt` would (IMHO) be to convert the input using the `-` operator: `(num1 - 0) + 1`

Comment: Wow... works like a charm. @GoloRoden your solution is super awesome.

Comment: You must not have an `ng-model` directive on the input field.

Comment: You should always specify the second parameter to parseInt due to differences in implementation. From Mozilla Developer Network: "Always specify this parameter... Different implementations produce different results when a radix is not specified."

Comment: @azium The reason (str - 0) works is because - is a mathematical operator only, so it has to convert the sides to numbers. +(str) doesn't work, because + is both mathematical and concatenation operator, meaning its valid for both numbers and strings.

Answer (score 7):

You can also use input type=number instead of text. This also has the added benefit of providing a type that matches what you expect to get.

Comment: Would be nice to be able to do this with `select` elements.

Answer (score 0):

num1 is being interpreted as a string.

Use *parseInt()* or  *parseDouble()* to convert this to a number when initializing it.

Answer (score 0):

I found a tick method to solve. My case is that I need to parseInt something like item.qty. But I found `<div ng-click="item.qty = parseInt(item.qty) + 1>Add</div>` won't work.

Finally, I found this method can solve

```
<div ng-click = "item.qty = item.qty - 1 + 2">Add</div>
```