# Perform calculation on ngModel value from input and then show calculated value

Tags: angularjs

I have a simple angular app that has an `ng-model` attached to an input that takes a width

```
<input type="text" placeholder="1280" ng-model="containerWidth">
```

I'm then showing the `containerWidth` value in a binding in the template further down the page `{{containerWidth}}`

I would like to  perform a simple calculation on the value that is typed into the input e.g simply adding 20 to the number.

I have tried adding `{{containerWidth + 20}}` but it does not have the desired effect as it just concats the strings of numbers.

Comment: why not make the input a `number` input?

Comment: I dont really want the system styles of the incrementer and decrementer in the input

Comment: can try {{Number(containerWidth) + 20}}

Comment: Unfortunately no luck with that

Comment: I updated my answer, it is tested and works properly as per your request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the input type to number:

```
<input type="number" placeholder="1280" ng-model="containerWidth">
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/michelem09/sb99uvc4/)

Answer (score 1):

In order to add an int to your input fields value, you will need to turn the string value that you are entering into the field into an integer using parseInt() (native js method). This is also a possible duplicate of [AngularJS how to add numbers inside the expression from a textbox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17444843/angularjs-how-to-add-numbers-inside-)

Here, the solution was to add the native JS parseInt into the scope to be used like this:

Inside controller:

```
$scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

In view/DOM:

```
<input type="text" value="{{ parseInt(num1) + 1 }}" />
```

Here is the script:

```
"use strict";
var demo = angular.module('demo',[]);

demo.controller('demo-controller', function($scope){
  $scope.parseInt = function(s){
   return parseInt(s, 10);
  };
});
```

Here is an interactive demo to support this solution:

http://codepen.io/nicholasabrams/pen/zGPWQx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

You can use parseInt. Although I support just changing the html to a number format. Here is how you would use parse int:

First in your controller you make:

```
 $scope.parseInt = parseInt;
```

This puts the parseInt function into the scope so you can use it in an expression.

Then you can write your expression like this:

```
{{parseInt(containerWidth) + 20}}
```